# Convert two columns based on the condition of string column and other columns 2 & 3 Pyspark UDF

Tags: pyspark, user-defined-functions, multiple-conditions

[image: data table]
Hello

I wanted to convert some of the cm values (ref_low = 20 and ref_low <40, & ref_high > 70 and ref_high <90,) to meter using the formula (cm/100). I tried to use Pyspark UDF

> c_udf = udf(lambda val: val/100 if ref_low = 20 and ref_low <40 else
>   val) df = df.withColumn("new", c_udf("ref_low")).withColumn("new", c_udf("ref_high"))

Question1: **How to add unit = Cm to the UDF?** and want to keep all other values as such.

Thanks

Comment: no need for a `udf` here. you can use `when/otherwise` clause to express your logic

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) also  provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want. Spark in-built **`when/otherwise`** are adequate. You just have to express the boolean appropriately.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.withColumn("ref_low", F.when((F.col("unit")=='cm')&((F.col("ref_low")<40)|\
                                 (F.col("ref_low")==20)), F.col("ref_low")/100)\
             .otherwise(F.col("ref_low")))\
  .withColumn("ref_high", F.when((F.col("unit")=='cm')&((F.col("ref_high")<90)&\
                                  (F.col("ref_high")>70)),F.col("ref_high")/100)\
             .otherwise(F.col("ref_high"))).show()

#+-----+-------+--------+
#| unit|ref_low|ref_high|
#+-----+-------+--------+
#|   cm|    0.3|    50.0|
#|   cm|   40.0|    70.0|
#|   cm|    0.2|    0.85|
#|   cm|    0.2|    0.85|
#|   cm|    0.3|    0.76|
#|   cm|   43.0|    65.0|
#|Meter|    0.2|    0.65|
#|Meter|    0.4|    0.68|
#|Meter|    0.5|     0.8|
#+-----+-------+--------+
```

Comment: Thank you, @Mohammad Murtaza Hashmi